# django return 404 uploading media file

Tags: django

hi I have a problem when I upload a file to the deployed server. It returns 404 does not matter if I do it by admin or by a view but if I can see the files that are already on the server.

I am hosting my app in namecheap on a shareserver and the settings are

> **settings.py**

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static-server')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

# Media folder for database media
MEDIA_URL = '/static-server/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static-server/media')
```

> **url.py**

```
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT, show_indexes=True)
```

switch between debug mode true or false on local and it works perfectly but not when I deploy ... if anyone has any ideas. Well, from namecheap support they answered that the error is not on their side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django does not serve media or static files in production as it just means to save the link for it. You need to use other services as Amazon Web Services S3 Bucket to serve it. But if you want to serve it anyway you can do in using Whitenoise.
First `pip install whitenoise` and then `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
Then in `settings.py`

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  # 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
  # ...
]
```

then add this line

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

then push this code to your production server and make sure you run collectstatic command i.e `python manage.py collectstatic` your static files now should be working.

Comment: cool man thanks, but now i got a [Errno 13] Permission denied: i think i will need change the media url and root ?

Comment: solved i add alias /media/ yn .htconfig now can able to upload files from view but not from the admin